# Change price location on single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

This is something that has been doing my head in and I can't seem to find exactly what I want on here.

I am trying to move the price on my product pages to display just above or beside the add to cart button.

[Page link for a product is here](http://ascentsofscotland.co.uk/product/bill-the-robin-brooch/)

I have played around with this before, and managed to create a second price in the position I wanted, but still had the original price at the top and couldn't get rid of it.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean adding the price left of the 'Add to Basket' button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work just for simple products as variable products displays already their live price above the Add-to-cart button.

This is the code you need:

```
function changing_price_location_for_simple_products(){
    global $product;

    if($product->is_type('simple')) // Only for simple products (thanks to helgathevicking)
    {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'changing_price_location_for_simple_products');
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file*.

The code is tested and works.

Comment: Don't you have to add a `remove_action()` to an `add_action()` hook?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've pulled my hair out over that one in the past. Much better answer now, +1. Though can I suggest using `$product->is_type('simple')` instead of `$product->product_type`. Direct access of class properties is going to throw PHP warnings in WC2.7. The class method `is_type()` is current and future compatible.

Comment: The good thing is `$product->product_type` won't break immediately. BUT, it will throw notices everywhere. My plugins are sold by Woo so I will have updates ready, but for themes and custom code, it's gonna be messy.

Comment: [Name Your Price](https://woocommerce.com/products/name-your-price/), [Mix and Match](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products/) and [Free Gift Coupons](https://woocommerce.com/products/free-gift-coupons/). Based on the number of commits/changes it probably should be bigger than a 2.7 release number. Hopefully plugins that rely on Woo are doing their best to get up to speed. Themes are almost always behind the 8 ball though.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for this! I have put the code in and works! My vaiiable products however didn't have the price in the area above the add to basket button and I would like this to also be the case. Is this as simple as amending this code or do I need completely different code.... sorry, but trying to get my head around this stuff....

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, forget that last comment... I took the line out of the code that was pointing to simple products and seems to be fine! Thanks Again!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Thanks! I had some products that had different options but were the same price and the price was at the top, but I managed to move it.

Comment: @LoicTheViking, I would also like to move the star rating from reviews down to this area too.... How would I do this? I assume it's the same principle, but not sure what to look for...   Thanks       Link here! https://ascentsofscotland.co.uk/product/multibuy-candle-offer/      Also another product here without options... https://ascentsofscotland.co.uk/product/eriskay-love/

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, sorry.... lol... I was also responding to helgatheviking regarding another question and got mixed up when typing your name... Yep thanks again for your help!