# Change the review rating location on single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, rating

Actually, In WooCommerce, I am using [**the code below**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513624/change-price-location-on-single-product-pages), to change the price location for my simple products:

```
function changing_price_location_for_simple_products(){
    global $product;

    if($product->is_type('simple')) // Only for simple products (thanks to helgathevicking)
    {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'changing_price_location_for_simple_products');
```

I would like to move the star rating from reviews down from the top of the page to appear above or to the right of my price.

Here the [live link to a product](http://ascentsofscotland.co.uk/product/eriskay-love)

Please, any help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the [**template**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) woocommerce file [**`content-single-product.php`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/content-single-product.php), you will see that inside:

```
    /**
     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

So this show you the different templates hooked in **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** action hook with their priorities (the little number at the end).

So you can [**reuse my code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513624/change-price-location-on-single-product-pages) and replace it with this one:

```
function customizing_simple_products(){
    global $product;

    if($product->is_type('simple')) // Only for simple products (thanks to helgathevicking)
    {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10); 
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25);
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 26); 
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'customizing_simple_products');
```

And you will need to add some CSS rules in the **`style.css`** of your active theme *(is better use a child theme)* to get the product price side by side with this ratings. For this you have to target the correct selectors and sometimes you will be obliged to add **`!important`** to that rules, to make them effective. You can also manipulate the priority numbers if needed in my answer function…

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and works.

Comment: If you use the plugin Simply Show Hooks you can see all of them and the priorities. Very good time saver!

Comment: @Christina Thanks for this info. I know already all of them :), but this is just to explain…

Comment: Excellent! Thankyou sooo much!