# Change position of rating and price using WordPress hooks - Priority Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have been using hit & try method from past 3 hours but could not get it working.
I am trying to swipe rating and position but not get it to work. In `functions.php` I have added following code at the end of file.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10);
function customizing_simple_products(){
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 26);
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'customizing_simple_products');
```

I also tried to change position from `woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php` But useless.
Please help me get out of this situation.

Comment: Why are you trying the removal directly, but then have adding your own actions wrapped into another function?

Comment: It looks weird that you have the same priority for woocommerce_template_single_price and woocommerce_template_single_rating, usually woocommerce default priorities differs from one to another. Beside that, if you made those tests and nothing changes i would try to look if somewhere else in your plugin/themes something is messing up with those hooks or the template file that gets loaded. Help yourself using "Query Monitor" plugin to see which template (and template parts) gets loaded

Comment: @CBroe I tried removal inside function also but nothing made difference.

Comment: @Diego it was same priority before I got hands on this issue. Also there is one similar question that has same priority too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531410/change-the-review-rating-location-on-single-product-pages

Comment: I don't know why one would try to trigger this via the `woocommerce_before_single_product` hook in the first place. If it doesn't work when added directly to the functions.php, then I'd try a hook such as `plugins_loaded`.